# Scrolling down to an anchor in an HTML frame

Tags: html, xslt, frameset

I've created an HTML document which is composed of 6 frames:

```
  <xsl:result-document href="frameset.html" method="html">
    <html>
      <frameset cols="15%,*,15%">
         <frameset rows="100,*">
              <frame name="logo" src="logo.html"/>
              <frame name="menu" src="menu.html"/>
         </frameset>
         <frameset rows="100,*">
              <frame name="title" src="title.html"/>
              <frame name="content" src="content.html"/>
         </frameset>
         <frameset rows="100,*">
              <frame name="search" src="search.html"/>
              <frame name="links" src="links.html"/>
         </frameset>
     </frameset>
    </html>
   </xsl:result-document>
```

What I'd like to do, is have it so when a user clicks on a link in menu.html, a new browser tab opens and presents the same 6 frames.  However, the content.html frame will be scrolled down to an anchor.

I've tried this code below and it scrolls down to the right spot, but it just gives me one frame in the new tab.  Not all 6.

```
<a href="content.html#ID{$linkID}" target="_blank"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
```

I've tried this code below and it gives me all 6 frames, but no way to scroll down to the anchor.

```
<a href="frameset.html" target="_blank"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
```

I need a way to sort of combine both these things into one.

Comment: try taking out the "{$linkID}" - what does that do?

Comment: @BruceWayne That will just open up the content page in a new browser tab and not scroll down to where I want

Comment: do you want an animated scroll down or just go to a specific part of the page automatically

Comment: try "frameset.html#ID"

Comment: It doesn't have to animate.  frameset.html#ID won't do it.  There is no anchor named ID.  And the anchors aren't in frameset.html, they're in content.html which is an html page within a frame in frameset.html

Comment: then try "content.html#ID" and try posting some code plz?? this seems interesting

Comment: content.html#ID{$linkID} scrolls me to the right spot.  But it only gives me that one frame in a new tab.  I'd like all my frames

Comment: Your question is unclear, more code and this idea of "one frame vs all of my frames" better explained would be helpful

Comment: @SerjSagan Sure, I'll try to explain better.  If you see my code above (the last code snippit), you'll see I'm creating 6 frames inside my html document frameset.html.  In menu.html (one of the frames inside frameset.html), I would like it so when the user clicks a link here a new tab opens up in the browser.  The new tab will have the same 6 frames as frameset.html, but the content.html frame will be scrolled down to the anchor

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is it really necessary for you to use frames? You may not realized this but HTML5 doesn't even support them anymore. Second of all, if this is a real business need to use frames, and there is absolutely no way around it, if I understand you properly, then your links will **all** need to be

```
<a href="frameset.html#ID{$linkID}" target="_blank"><xsl:apply-templates/></a>
```